# PHP setting cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I learned that when you set cookies, you give them a name, a value, and an expiration. This is an example I got from a book.

```
setcookie('test', 45, time()(60*60*24));
```

I understand the purpose of  setting a name, so we have a way of referring to it. And I understand the purpose of setting the expiry date, but what is the purpose of setting a value?  Why would we need to set a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is the very reason for which you are setting the cookie: so that the next time the browser makes a request, it repeats the value you gave it earlier back to you.

In some occasions, even repeating just the name would be useful (in essence you are getting back *one bit* of information by the presence or absence of the name). Adding a value lets you keep more than one bit.

So why keep the name if there's going to be a value anyway? Because cookies with different names can have different expiration times, and because it can be convenient for separate components of an application or system to have a cookie dedicated to each one of them. This way, you don't need to account for what component A did to the cookie value when you are setting (overwriting) it from component B. You have a value all to yourself, distinguished by its name.

For completeness, I should mention that there are also other cookie attributes that can be set per-cookie (i.e. per distinct name):

- Domain (cookie is valid only on specific domain and subdomains)
- Path (cookie is valid only on specific request path and below)
- Secure/HttpOnly (however, these cookies can have no value)

Comment: but why couldn't it just repeat the name you gave it, if you're seeking a way to identify it. Why do you need that value? What do you do with it?  Please explain more if you can. thank you.

Comment: @Michael - It could repeat the key in the value; the value is just a setting you can get by calling the name you gave it (key). It can be nothing, it can be same as the key (name), it can be anything you set it to (within reason).

Comment: actually, it says that values are optional, so I don't see why your answer is correct.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @Jared Farrish, but why do you want the value. If the importance of the cookie is presence, and that can be achieved by name, then what's the purpose of the 45 in the OP for example?

Comment: @Michael - It's not wrong, he's just giving you the reason you would set a value, so that you can retrieve it.

Comment: @Michael: Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: @Michael - You're overthinking it. Having a cookie be present is NOT the primary reason you have a cookie; it's meant to store a small ("cookie-size") piece of data accessible to the browser and the server. Cookies are meant to store data, just are not REQUIRED to.

Comment: o.k., it's still unclear but maybe because these are just examples. So values are not usually arbitrary numbers used to identify, but actual pieces of information that you want remembered, even though you're not supposed to store sensitive information? Would you for example store a birthdate in a value? or some other "real" number?

Comment: when the guy in my book gave his example, he set the value to 45. when he unset the cookie, he changed the value to 0. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Michael: Usually what happens is that you set the value to a modest-length unique string id (e.g. 20 chars or so). When the server sees that value (which is opaque to everyone on the internet) it uses it as the *key* to another key => value store that only it has access to (e.g. the key is a file name and the value is whatever you can stuff inside). This way it gets hold of personally identifiable information for the browser who sent the cookie back without anyone else being able to do so. This very example is how PHP implements sessions in its default configuration.

Comment: @Michael: The guy in the book probably only used the cookie in a manner similar to `if ($_COOKIE['test']) { ... }`, in which case the 0 would evaluate to `false` and this would behave "as if the cookie were not set". Advice: ditch that book and get a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are key = value pairs. Just the presence of a cookie could be useful (even if nothing), but it's ultimately meant to store a value retrievable by key (name).

And technically you don't need the value or expiry: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

The value of the cookie. This value is stored on the clients computer; do not store sensitive information. Assuming the name is 'cookiename', this value is retrieved through $_COOKIE['cookiename']

Also Check: 
[PHP setcookie Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp);
[PHP setcookie Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)